# The security domain other has been disabled. All authentication will fail

Tags: java, security, jboss

I have following standalone config:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Disabled" flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="DBAuthTest">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/Postgres"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from  UserHibernate where name=?"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select user_role, role_group from UserRoleHibernate inner join UserHibernate on UserRoleHibernate.user_id = UserHibernate.user_id  where n$
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
```

All sql are tested and works fine. DB connection is alright. I am getting exception:

```
13:05:41,115 ERROR [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) PBOX000265: The security domain other has been disabled. All authentication will fail
13:05:41,115 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) PBOX000206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Login Failure: all modules ignored
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:913) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:203) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:687) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:595) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.defaultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:408) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2.jar:4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.proceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:345) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2.jar:4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.authenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:333) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2.jar:4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.isValid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:146) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2.jar:4.0.17.SP2-redhat-2]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.java:216) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:280) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:391) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.1.Final-redhat-10.jar:7.2.1.Final-redhat-10]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
```

What is the possible reason of the issue?

Comment: Refer https://developer.jboss.org/thread/229343?tstart=0

Comment: I found out that annotation `@Webservice` some how cause this. Btw annotation was on `EJB` class that not involved into login process